# Execute sequelize-cli from .js file

Tags: node.js

I am calling a **migration.js** file from the `scripts` portion in package.json

The **migration.js** file needs to execute a command line `sequelize-cli` call

So far I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
console.log("hello");
npx sequelize-cli db:migrate //this works in the command line but not in the migration.js script
```

How can I execute `npx sequelize-cli db:migrate` from the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find this clunky, but it is possible to plainly execute the `sequelize-cli` as a shell command with the `node-cmd` module.

```
var cmd=require('node-cmd');
cmd.run('npx sequelize-cli db:migrate');
```

Seems like it would be better to require the `sequelize-cli` in the js file.